# Why geth fast sync or light sync does not get the latest highest block

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, blocks, fast-sync

I am running geth "light" mode: *geth --syncmode "fast" console*.  I have the following problem. The highest block is always be 13773036, which is created at 3 days ago:

```
web3.eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 13125823,
  highestBlock: 13773036,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 13008895
}
```

While I am writing this question, the highest block on etherscan is already 13794774. https://etherscan.io/block/13794774. Why my geth doesn't get the latest highest block?

I also tried the geth in "fast" mode: *geth --syncmode "fast" console*. But it is still at the same highest block 13773036. Could anyone help on this issue?

**Update:**

It is probably reaching block 13773036 now, and it shows:

```
> web3.eth.syncing
false
> web3.eth.blockNumber
13773036
```

The current log is:

```
INFO [12-13|04:49:39.556] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=1 static=0
INFO [12-13|04:50:05.201] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=0 static=0
INFO [12-13|04:50:29.195] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=1 static=0
INFO [12-13|04:50:40.204] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=0 static=0
INFO [12-13|04:51:07.542] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=0 static=0
```

Comment: Check GoEthereum logs to see if the geth is working and importing new blocks.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa It shows only "INFO [12-13|04:50:29.195] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=1 static=0", and now web3.eth.syncing shows "false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced exactly the same problem (last block 13773036). The solution was to update the geth to the latest version.

Comment: Oh yes, there was a hard fork three days ago, so any node that is not up-to-date cannot sync beyond that block.

Answer (score 0):

`peercount=0` means that your node cannot connect to other Ethereum peer-to-peer nodes. Probably a firewall or a network issue. To make your node more robust, make sure your node is not behind NAT and has a good public IP address.